# Проблема с выборкой данных в HQL запросе

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

У меня есть энтити, сервис, DAO и контроллер. Начнём по порядку.

Энтити (Schedule.java):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "schedule")
public class Schedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "date_departure")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateDeparture;

    @Column(name = "date_arrival")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateArrival;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "station_departure_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Station stationDeparture;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "station_arrival_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Station stationArrival;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "train_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Train train;


    public Schedule() {
    }

    public Schedule(Date dateDeparture, Date dateArrival, Station stationDeparture, Station stationArrival, Train train) {
        this.dateDeparture = dateDeparture;
        this.dateArrival = dateArrival;
        this.stationDeparture = stationDeparture;
        this.stationArrival = stationArrival;
        this.train = train;
    }
    // getters & setters...
    ...
    }
```

Конкретное представление через SQL (создавал эту БД через следующий DDL):

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date_departure TIMESTAMP NULL,
  date_arrival TIMESTAMP NULL,
  station_departure_id INT NULL,
  station_arrival_id INT NULL,
  train_id INT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT schedule_station_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (station_departure_id) REFERENCES station (id),
  CONSTRAINT schedule_station_id_fk_2 FOREIGN KEY (station_arrival_id) REFERENCES station (id),
    CONSTRAINT schedule_train_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(train_id) references train (id)
);
```

Сервис, который осуществляет работу с DAO (ScheduleService и ScheduleServiceImpl):

Интерфейс

```
 @Service
    public interface ScheduleService {

        List<Schedule> getByStationsAndDate(Schedule schedule);

        List<Schedule> getAllSchedules();
    }
```

И имплементация

```
 @Service
    public class ScheduleServiceImpl implements ScheduleService {

        @Autowired
        private ScheduleDAO scheduleDAO;

        @Transactional
        public List<Schedule> getByStationsAndDate(Schedule schedule) {
            return scheduleDAO.getByStationsAndDate(schedule);
        }

        @Transactional
        public List<Schedule> getAllSchedules() {
            return scheduleDAO.getAll();
        }
    }
```

Теперь DAO. У DAO тоже есть интерфейс, но тут немного тонкий момент. В моём ScheduleDAOImpl есть несколько методов, которые выбирают данные из базы по определённым критериям. И так же есть метод, который просто возвращает все записи. Причём, метод, который возвращает все записи - работает прекрасно. А вот этот HQL вообще ничего не возвращает:

```
public List<Schedule> getByStationsAndDates(Schedule schedule) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Schedule where " +
                    "stationArrival = :stationArrival and " +
                    "stationDeparture = :stationDeparture and " +
                    "date(dateDeparture) = :date " +
                    "order by dateDeparture desc ")
            .setParameter("stationArrival", schedule.getStationArrival())
            .setParameter("stationDeparture", schedule.getStationDeparture())
            .setParameter("date", schedule.getDateDeparture())
            .getResultList();
    }
```

В моём контроллере имеется два маппинг-метода, первый селектит данные, которые пользователь вводит, а второй вытаскивает нужные записи по выбранным данным пользователя:

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/scheduleByStationsAndDate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public String scheduleByStationsAndDatePersist(@ModelAttribute Schedule schedule, BindingResult result, Model model) {

                Date today = new Date();


                if (schedule.getDateDeparture() == null)
                    schedule.setDateDeparture(today);


        // Вытаскиваем только строки, а нам нужно связать записи реальными объектами        

  schedule.setStationDeparture(stationService.getStationByName(schedule.getStationDeparture().getName()));
                schedule.setStationArrival(stationService.getStationByName(schedule.getStationArrival().getName()));

                // Список пуст!
                List<Schedule> schedules = scheduleService.getByStationsAndDate(schedule);

                model.addAttribute("schedules", schedules);

                return JspFormNames.SCHEDULE_INPUT_FOR_STATIONS_AND_DATE_RESULT;
            }
```

UPDATE:

Помимо этого, я решил проверить HQL запрос и сделать это ручками. Вот такой вот код (отрывочно):

```
            session.beginTransaction();

            Station s1 = session.get(Station.class, 1l);
            Station s2 = session.get(Station.class, 2l);
            Train t1 = session.get(Train.class, 1l);

            System.out.println("Start");
            List<Schedule> schedules = session
                    .createQuery("from Schedule where " +
                            "stationArrival = :stationArrival and " +
                            "stationDeparture = :stationDeparture")
                    .setParameter("stationArrival", s1)
                    .setParameter("stationDeparture", s2)
                    .getResultList();

            System.out.println("SIZE OF LIST " + schedules.size());
            for (Schedule schedule: schedules) {
                System.out.println("Element: " + schedule.getStationDeparture() + " " + schedule.getStationArrival());
            }


            session.getTransaction().commit();
```

И вот лог:

```
Start
Hibernate: select schedule0_.id as id1_0_, schedule0_.date_arrival as date_arr2_0_, schedule0_.date_departure as date_dep3_0_, schedule0_.station_arrival_id as station_4_0_, schedule0_.station_departure_id as station_5_0_, schedule0_.train_id as train_id6_0_ from schedule schedule0_ where schedule0_.station_arrival_id=? and schedule0_.station_departure_id=?
SIZE OF LIST 0
```

Видимо, проблема заключается исключительно в HQL запросе...

Никак не могу понять, почему HQL запрос ничего не возвращает?

Comment: Не вижу чтоб "dateArrival" в hql задавался.

Comment: Код почему-то полностью не скопировался. Но у меня он передаётся, сейчас подправлю вопрос

Comment: Кстати, а пробовали отобразить в консоли сконвертированные sql запросы и проверить их непосредственно в бд?

Comment: Прямо сейчас я в консоли проверил через sessionFactory этот же HQL, только я упростил его до станции отправления и станции прибытия (чтобы не заморачиваться с датой). У меня этот HQL вернул 0... Сейчас обновлю вопрос

Comment: Нееет, в хабере можно включить отображение sql в консоли. Т.е. он отобразит в терминале sql сформированный из твоего hql. Попробуй его оттуда получить и посмотреть что там не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, у меня был неверный HQL запрос. Мне надо было использовать alias'ы, так как поля энтити (stationDeparture и stationArrival) имеют реляционный тип many-to-one. Написал это и заработало:

```
 String QUERY = "from Schedule s where s.stationDeparture = :stationDeparture and s.stationArrival = :stationArrival and date(dateDeparture) = :date";

 return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(QUERY)
                .setParameter("stationArrival", schedule.getStationArrival())
                .setParameter("stationDeparture", schedule.getStationDeparture())
                .setParameter("date", schedule.dateDeparture)
                .getResultList();
```